# Change sublime text 2 folding style?

Tags: ide, editor, sublimetext2

Is there any way in sublime text 2 to change the default folding style (With example code):

```
function()
{
    // This line will be folded
}
```

From this:

```
function()
{[...]
}
```

To this?

```
function()
{[...]}
```

Or even better, to this:

```
function() {[...]}
```

(So the `{` will collapse to the previous line if it is not empty?)
Note that I am a Sublime Text noob, there's probably some regex stuff that I don't know of.